# Does the US public find credible excuses by some Senators that Justices who overturned Roe had misled them in Senate hearings?

Tags: united-states, senate, supreme-court, public-opinion, nomination

[Two](https://www.nbcnews.com/politics/supreme-court/collins-manchin-misled-kavanaugh-gorsuch-abortion-rights-rcna35230) or even [three](https://www.politico.com/news/2022/05/08/supreme-court-justices-misled-the-senate-gillibrand-said-00030900) US Senators have said that [future] justices that ultimately overturned *Roe* had essentially lied to them, or at least seriously misled them in the Senate hearings on their nominations.

This might be too-obscure of a matter to have been polled, but... does the US public find such excuses credible? I.e. that some Senators were really thinking those Justices would uphold *Roe*?

Comment: Anyway, the appointment is probably final. You can lie but once you are a supreme court judge your word has godlike powers. These senators basically had to factor in the possibility that applicants may lie.

Comment: Even if they did, it's not the Senate's job to appoint people they like to the courts (that's the President's job, as they check the courts). It's the Senate's job to check that the appointee is qualified for the job. It's the court's job to check the legislative branch so giving them too much control over who checks them is counterproductive.

Comment: @Trilarion: The House could theoretically impeach the justices for lying to the Senate, but that will probably never happen (and even if it did, a conviction is profoundly unlikely).

Comment: For what it is worth, most people call the case *Roe* for short.

Comment: @uberhaxed `with the Advice and Consent of the Senate` is the Constitutional wording, so I don't think it's limited to qualifications only. To be fair, I don't think I've ever seen the Senate ever formally give "advice" as to what judge to appoint.